# Log when a character is replaced in Scala

Tags: scala, character-encoding

Right now, we are using

```
val codec = scala.io.Codec.UTF8
codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
```

to simply replace bad characters. I would like to know if there is a way to know that the replacement occurred? We would like to inform our customers that the data they sent us was malformed. Is there a way to do this in Scala or Java?

Thanks